# To output a file to a user's browser, does it need to be saved on disk first? PHP

Tags: php, download, plist

I have a web app that builds an associative array of responses from a user as they take a survey. When completed, I want to allow them to press a button, and have their responses download to their browser as a plist.

Using `file_put_contents`, I am able to write the array to disk and then downloading it from there is pretty easy. I am wondering if it is possible to output the plist file without writing it to disk first? It seems like a lot of overhead and cleanup will be required if I am writing to disk every time.

Can I just take the array and output to a select filename and extension?

Thanks

Comment: You can just read the temp file.  Then after the session is destroyed the file will be deleted automatically.

Comment: I have never coded a line of PHP in my life... But in other frameworks, you can write files directly to the HTTP response stream, so you really don't have to write stuff in the disk. Therefore it should be possible in PHP too. I hope somebody more savvy than me comes by and gives you a code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have no other output then it is possible see. 
[serving pdf file using php header produces the pdf source instead of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244421/serving-pdf-file-using-php-header-produces-the-pdf-source-instead-of-the-file)

using the headers and just outputting your array, in a fomat you wish.

Comment: "outputting the array in the format I wish", are you saying I just echo the array in the format it needs to be in?

Answer (score 0):

Create the necessary headers (as per your other question :-)

And then simply echo the content out after the headers.